# Cannot use python in VSCode

Tags: python, installation, terminal

I simply want be able to execute python commands in VSCode.
I have already installed it by the marketplace and the main software on my computer.
Once I would have finished the python problem I am looking to install brownie, but I first need the ability to execute python commands in the VSCode terminal "pip install...".

Can you help me out?

Comment: Can you run `where python` in cmd?

Comment: Have you added python to your path?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but this may answer your question: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Comment: Sadly I cant run "where python"
How do I find and add python to my path?

Comment: I can now use the pip command, so I am trying to install pip ex via python 3
This time it cannot find python 3
"$ python3 -m pip install --user pipx
bash: python3: command not found"